# Type 'Workers.Type' has no subscript members Error with Collection Views

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I am coding a UIViewCollection to get some data from the Firebase Database.
I am not sure why I am getting this error. I did create a Workers file with all the info to connect to the firebase but still get "Type 'Workers.Type' has no subscript members"

I have the worker file here:

```
class Workers { 
    var workerName = ""
    var workerFrequency = ""
    var workerLocation = ""
    var workerNextAppointment = ""
}
```

My problem is when configuring the collection view mandatory fields. See below;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkerCell", for: indexPath) as! WorkerCell

    let cellUsers = Workers[indexPath.item]


    cell.workerName.text = cellUsers.name
    cell.workerLocation.text = ""

    return cell

    //if let profileImageURL = cellUsers.profileImageURL {


       // cell.usersImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageURL)
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what is the issue here?

Comment: `let cellUsers = Workers[indexPath.item]` You meant `let cellUsers = user[indexPath.item]`? You are doing `MyClass[someIndex]`, `MyClass` is not an array, it's a Class.

Comment: I see, so I should add the Worker to an Array instead?

Comment: Isn't `user` already the array where you put all your `Workers`s object? Because I saw `return user.count` in `collectionView(_ collectionView: numberOfItemsInSection:) `?

Comment: If I use the user, the "let cellUsers" doesn't present the options I need to add.

Comment: @AlexGrinberg where are you storing the workers then?

Comment: Thanks Guys, works now